# Why page load of APEX takes a long time : "... do not save: same value / password / no session"

Tags: oracle-apex

When load a page in Oracle APEX, it takes a long time. I debugged it, the part that takes a long time is "... do not save: same value / password / no session". how can i solve this problem?  TNX

[image]

Comment: This will be tricky without more details as that's just a debug message. Assuming the performance issue is consistent and repeatable: was an item being assigned a value? What was the source for the item? In fact, the performance issue might be unrelated to your APEX page at all.

Comment: There isn't any details. APEX show just it.

Comment: Hmmm, can't see what's wrong yet. It looks like you have sorted the debug log by Execution time. What does it look like if you sort by time, so we can see what the logs say just before that line?

Comment: TNX Jeffrey. I sorted the logs by time. You can see it in above.

Comment: It sounds, the problem happens in line 5

Comment: Perhaps look at Q_YEAR and see how it is being derived? I'm not sure if that is the problem or not but it's worth checking. Also, confirm that the same issue occurs at the same point every time the page loads.

Comment: I'm guessing that's when the query was executed. If it's printing rows right after, it had to get them from somewhere. What kind of region to you have on the page on the page? If it's a report region, did you try running the query outside of APEX?

Comment: Yes, I executed the query in Navicat. It executed fast.

Comment: Region type is Interactive Report.

Comment: I executed Debug mode at LEVEL8. I got more details and found out that the time is spent in "fetch_rows". see :   [link](https://pasteboard.co/IRIDwYrh.jpg )   , how can  i reduce time of "fetch_rows"?